# Append one form to another jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have two forms, I would like to append all input fields from second form to the first form, dynamically during form one submission. I would prefer jquery. I would like to append as hidden input. I have working solution in javascript

Comment: We would prefer to see your attempt.

Comment: look at form selectors in jQuery API...this is really fairly simple to make an attempt at  http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: I would like to append without removing from the original(copy and paste) I would also like to hide copied inputs

Comment: This is someone who is looking for this kind of solution try the below cdoe 



if($(".temphiddenfields").length){
 $(".temphiddenfields").remove();
}
$('#form1').find('input').each(function(){
  $("#form2").append("<input type='hidden' name="+$(this).attr("name")+" value="+$(this).val()+" class='temphiddenfields' />");
});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#form1").find(":input").appendTo("#form2");
```

Comment: works but  it actually removes inputs from the original form

Comment: Your question said you wanted to "append all input fields".  You can `.clone()` the inputs and append them if you actually wanted to copy all of the input fields.

Comment: clone works fine, `.find(":input").clone().appendTo`. make cloned inputs hidden?